# Ionic Framework: ionic serve failing in example projects after fresh install

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm running Windows 7 64-bit and currently attempting to set up the Ionic Framework. I've had everything working fine in v1, but after fixing some VCBuild-related issues by installing a Windows SDK, `ionic serve` fails after creating a new project via `ionic start MyApp blank --v2`.

I get normal output from the script:

```
[20:53:13]  ionic-app-scripts 0.0.43
[20:53:13]  watch started ...
[20:53:13]  build dev started ...
[20:53:13]  clean started ...
[20:53:13]  clean finished in 16 ms
[20:53:13]  copy started ...
[20:53:13]  transpile started ...
[20:53:18]  transpile finished in 5.17 s
[20:53:18]  webpack started ...
[20:53:18]  copy finished in 5.40 s
[20:53:18]  webpack finished in 281 ms
[20:53:18]  sass started ...
[20:53:20]  sass finished in 1.33 s
[20:53:20]  build dev finished in 6.79 s
[20:53:20]  watch ready in 6.95 s
[20:53:20]  dev server running: http://localhost:8100/
```

But the page delivered in-browser is blank with the following Javascript error in the console:

```
Uncaught Error: Module build failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'content' of undefined
    at Object.typescriptSourcemapLoaderMemory (C:\Users\Me\Documents\ionic\MyApp\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\dist\webpack\typescript-sourcemap-loader-memory.js:18:34)
    at Object.typescriptSourcemapLoaderMemory (C:\Users\Me\Documents\ionic\MyApp\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\dist\webpack\typescript-sourcemap-loader-memory.js:18:34)
    at eval (webpack:///C:/Users/Me/Documents/ionic/MyApp/src/app/main.dev.ts?:1:7)
    at Object.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:71:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:20:30)
    at http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:64:18
    at http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:67:10
```

Upon further inspection, the www/build/main.js file that should be built from the typescript source has the source of this error at the end:

```
/******/ ([
/* 0 */
/***/ function(module, exports) {

eval("throw new Error(\"Module build failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'content' of undefined\\n    at Object.typescriptSourcemapLoaderMemory (C:\\\\Users\\\\Mack\\\\Documents\\\\ionic\\\\chatroom\\\\node_modules\\\\@ionic\\\\app-scripts\\\\dist\\\\webpack\\\\typescript-sourcemap-loader-memory.js:18:34)\");\n\n//////////////////\n// WEBPACK FOOTER\n// C:/Users/Mack/Documents/ionic/chatroom/src/app/main.dev.ts\n// module id = 0\n// module chunks = 0\n\n//# sourceURL=webpack:///C:/Users/Mack/Documents/ionic/chatroom/src/app/main.dev.ts?");

/***/ }
/******/ ]);
```

So it appears that the problem lies in the typescript build process - but none of the scripts complain. Cleaning and/or manually deleting the www/build directory has no effect, the file is rebuilt identically.

How does one go about fixing this problem? I have searched but haven't found this issue anywhere else.

Comment: could you add the contents of your main.dev.ts to your post? Would be helpful I guess ;)

Comment: @OClyde All source is just from the "blank" example project.

Answer (score 0):

Try an older version of `ionic-app-scripts`. You can force to install a specific version by `npm install ionic-app-scripts@0.0.38` for example.